# How to register Win32 and Win64 component in Embarcadero C++Builder 11 Alexandria

Tags: c++, package, c++builder, win64, bpl

I can't find information on how to register a component (a Package) in Embarcadero C++Builder 11 Alexandria Professional, to be used for both 32-bit and 64-bit projects.

Some informations that I found is in https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/64-bit_Windows_Application_Development.

I saw that for Delphi, you have to use the following syntax (which I found in a 2014 forum):

```
unit agnosticu;

interface

uses
  System.Classes;

type
  TAgnosticComponent = class(TComponent)
  end;

  [ComponentPlatforms(pidWin32)]
  TWin32Component = class(TComponent)
  end;

  [ComponentPlatforms(pidWin64)]
  TWin64Component = class(TComponent)
  end;

procedure Register;

implementation

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('Test', [TAgnosticComponent, TWin32Component, TWin64Component]);
end;

end.
```

In C++, I seem to have understood that I need to modify the following section of code:

```
namespace Mycomponent
{
    void __fastcall PACKAGE Register()
    {
         TComponentClass classes[1] = {__classid(TMyComponent)};
         RegisterComponents(L"MyCategory", classes, 0);
    }
}
```

But regarding C++, I don't find any information on this.

I seem to understand that I should use the `ComponentPlatformsAttribute` class and the `pidWin32` and `pidWin64` attributes, but I don't know how.

Or, with C++, is the only solution to modify the `PLATFORMTARGETS` variable of the `RC_DATA` resource?

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Just to clarify things: there is no such thing as *32 and 64 bit component registration*. Components are only  registered for use in the IDE, which is 32-bit only, so no component is ever registered for 64-bit. Components are used in 64-bit applications, but they're not *registered* for 64-bit, just compiled for 64-bit when the 64-bit application/BPL is built/compiled.

Answer (score 0):

Doing some tests I realized that it is not necessary to make any changes to the original code.
The presence of the 64-bit Platform is enough to have the variable 'PLATFORMTARGETS' of the .BPL file (of the 32-bit version) set to the value 3, i.e. package compatible with both 32 and 64 bits (instead of the previous value 1 corresponding to only 32 bit).